Unable to connect with AWS IOT Core with python script
I am trying learn AWS IOT Core, for this I have followed few tutorials and successfully tested AWS IOT Core with ESP32 module. Now I am trying to do the same with a python script on my windows PC. I am trying run following code:-
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import ssl
import json
import threading


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))


client = mqtt.Client(mqtt.CallbackAPIVersion.VERSION2)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.tls_set(ca_certs='./AmazonRootCA1.pem', certfile='./ESP32Cert.crt', keyfile='./ESP32PRIV.key', tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
client.tls_insecure_set(True)
client.connect("a2d8i5t4axqj4h-ats.iot.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com", 8883, 60) #Taken from REST API endpoint - Use your own. 


def intrusionDetector(Dummy):
    while (1):    
        print("publishing data") 
        client.publish("esp32/pub", payload="Hello from my python code!!" , qos=0, retain=False)
        time.sleep(5)

thread = threading.Thread(target=intrusionDetector, args=("test",))

# Start the thread
thread.start()
    
client.loop_forever()

on running my code, it's never calling function on_connect. Why I am not able to connect with AWS IOT Core with this code??
